# Are the standard errors produced by R's plm package for weighted models reliable?

Tags: r, panel-data, lm, plm

I have a strong feeling there is a bug in R's `plm` package when it comes to the standard errors of weighted models. I have noticed that the standard errors are not invariant under multiplications with constants. Consider

```
PL <- plm(DF$value ~ treat+timed+countrd+infl+gdp, data=DF, weights=c(NLw,w), model="pooling")
coeftest(PL, vcov=vcovHC(PL, method="arellano"))
```

R reports

```
                  Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.2238888  0.0337502  36.2631 < 2.2e-16 ***
treat        1.5431316  0.0309765  49.8162 < 2.2e-16 ***
timed       -0.2338141  0.0155488 -15.0374 < 2.2e-16 ***
countrd     -0.5476585  0.0318385 -17.2011 < 2.2e-16 ***
infl         0.2065393  0.0116055  17.7967 < 2.2e-16 ***
gdp         -0.0266270  0.0061964  -4.2972 1.757e-05 ***
```

But when I multiply the weights with 100, the standard errors increase with a factor $\sqrt{100}=10$.

```
PL <- plm(DF$value ~ treat+timed+countrd+infl+gdp, data=DF, weights=c(NLw*100,w*100), model="pooling")
coeftest(PL, vcov=vcovHC(PL, method="arellano"))

                 Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.223889   0.337502  3.6263 0.0002899 ***
treat        1.543132   0.309765  4.9816 6.481e-07 ***
timed       -0.233814   0.155488 -1.5037 0.1326994    
countrd     -0.547659   0.318385 -1.7201 0.0854630 .  
infl         0.206539   0.116055  1.7797 0.0751801 .  
gdp         -0.026627   0.061964 -0.4297 0.6674176
```

Doing the same analysis with R's lm function, I get

```
PL <- lm(DF$value ~ treat+timed+countrd+infl+gdp, data=DF, weights=c(NLw,w))
coeftest(PL, vcov=vcovHC(PL, method="arellano")

                 Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.223889   0.345834  3.5389 0.0004047 ***
treat        1.543132   0.322387  4.7866 1.737e-06 ***
timed       -0.233814   0.247729 -0.9438 0.3452942    
countrd     -0.547659   0.190980 -2.8676 0.0041500 ** 
infl         0.206539   0.133016  1.5527 0.1205380    
gdp         -0.026627   0.068928 -0.3863 0.6992868
```

Furthermore, R's `lm` function standard errors are invariant under multiplying the weights with a constant. Could anyone tell me why this is not the case for the `plm` package?

Comment: The "standard standard" errors are reliable also in the case of a weighted regression with plm. But anything involving a call to plm's `vcovXX` functions is not reliable currently - you can see that in the development version of the package where calling one of the `vcovXX` functions on a weighted regression models errors with a note that it is not implemented. Maybe the `sandwich` package provides some function for weighted panel models, but I don't know.